# Using Replace With for Returning Last Value of an Array

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop in part with an array inside an object. It replaces, but it will only change the word(s) that are at the back of the array.

```
<textarea id='inp'></textarea>
<button onClick='rd()'>
k m8
</button>
<div id='res'>
</div>

<script>
var rd = function() {
var rep = "";
var inpt = document.getElementById('inp').value;
    for (i = 0; i < dict.before.length; i++) {
    var rep = inpt.replace(dict.before[i],dict.after[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = rep;
}

var dict = {
    before : ["for","to","too"],
  after : ["4","2","2"]
}
</script>
```

If at the end of the before array, the value was "this" and after would be "that", all the other strings in each array would not work, they do not replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are overwriting the `rep` variable in each iteration of the `for` loop. You can simply perform replacement using the original `init`, i.e., change this line:

```
 var rep = inpt.replace(dict.before[i],dict.after[i]);
```

…to this line:

```
inpt = inpt.replace(dict.before[i],dict.after[i]);
```

And use the replaced `inpt` to set the innerHTML: `document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = inpt;`

See working example below:

```js
var rd = function() {
  var rep = "";
  var inpt = document.getElementById('inp').value;
  for (i = 0; i < dict.before.length; i++) {
    inpt = inpt.replace(dict.before[i], dict.after[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = inpt;
}

var dict = {
  before: ["for", "to", "too"],
  after: ["4", "2", "2"]
}
```

```html
<textarea id='inp'></textarea>
<button onClick='rd()'>
  k m8
</button>
<div id='res'>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is it only replaces once, and when it should replace after it, it doesn't.